# Parser throwing error on particular instance of frequently used array field instance

Tags: php

I have one script which has several lines of code similar to this one:

```
if ($SetUpArray[$TableName.'_'.$Index.'_InView']) 
    { /// xxx code
    }
```

But when the script is run the parser throws:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in /home/segucom/public_html/CRUD/ShowColumn.php on line 192.

Interestingly it just started happening today. The code has several constructed array descriptors before this one, very similar to it:  (v.gr. "_Editable" vs "_Inview")  and do not throw errors on them.

Even more interesting is that I can reproduce it on a live site, but the line itsef do no throw an error if tested on www.phpfiddle.org.

Below is my test code used in phpfiddle:

```
<?php

$SetUpArray = array();
$TableName = "contabilidad";
$Index = 1;

// Make an assignment
$SetUpArray[$TableName.'_'.$Index.'_FieldName'] = 7;

// Another assignment
$FieldName = trim($SetUpArray[$TableName.'_'.$Index.'_FieldName']);   

// Test for value
if ($SetUpArray[$TableName.'_'.$Index.'_FieldName'] == 7)
    {
    echo "I accepted the assignment";
    } else {echo "I did not understood the assignment";}

?>
```

The code runs with no errors, and I got the expected output:

I accepted the assignment.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being the parser error thrown being quite off the issue.

The issue was that at some point I included a previously written heredoc block inside an new `if` statement for which I indented all the code including the heredoc block. Trying to run the code after many other changes, the parser did not find the end of the heredoc block because it was not placed at the beginning of the line, and kept reading until it found something it could not understand, in my case, the particular:

```
$SetUpArray[$TableName.'_'.$Index.'_InView']
```

statement.

Lesson learned, beware of beautifying or indenting code with heredoc blocks, and not checking that the closing heredoc statement (v.gr "EOD;") is placed exactly at the beginning of the line.
The parser very likely will give a weird error which could be difficult to track.  (Not its fault.)